# Is there a better way to map using Flat File in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-migration, kingswaysoft

I am migrating data to a Dynamic 365 database from a CSV file using flat file source in SSIS(kingswaysoft), most of have the data has migrated, but some fields failed. The error being that, it was trying map the column values close to the one it is meant to use to the field in in my D365 database. e.g, rather than map the "createdBy" field, it is trying to "permission to contact" field to the D365 Createdby field.

I have deleted the close by column and it still moves to the closest column, trying to map that one.

> error code ",,,CON-115388,,,,,Dexter,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,-1,KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.LookupFailureException: Text lookup failed for 'createdby' field, entity 'systemuser' does not contain a record that has a value of 'TRUE' for 'fullname' field (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v11.0.0.7160 - DtsDebugHost, v13.0.4495.10)"

I expect the Createdby to be mapped to the cretedby column in my Csv, but rather it is being mapped to a boolean column. I am such I mapped it properly in the flat file manager.

Comment: Check the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781017/how-to-map-input-and-output-columns-dynamically-in-ssis/54797147#54797147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SSIS column mapping is not dynamic and you will need to set it manually. There is one caveat, however, and that is SSIS will automatically map columns where the column name matches.

I do not understand what you mean by the CreateBy column mapping to the "Permission to Contact" column. I do not think SSIS will do that automatically.

Comment: I have manually mapped, but for some reasons, some fields mapped in the background to another column in the excel file.

Comment: @VictorOnyebuchi The only way behavior like that can occur is if you have not identified a text qualifier, such as; double quotes. In that case, if you have a text string that also includes a column delimiter, then the data will overflow into another column.

Comment: this resolved this, i completely forgot the file format could affect. Thanks