# Import XML files with different structures using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

I have multiple XML files with different structures, yet they all share a specific set of nodes.

My objective is to only import those mutual nodes into an SQL Server table.
How can I proceed, knowing that I can't generate an .Xsd for every type as there are many possible XML files variations?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use a script task to load into an XML document and then use LINQ to query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did as a solution to this particular case was:
1- add a C# script that reads the xml file and keep the common nodes only and save their values to my dts variables.
2- insert into my SQL Server table the variables I just populated.
Both tasks were in a for each loop to go through all the xml files in a specific directory.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Happy for getting things solved. Even after deaccepting my answer while it provided this solution :). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to load all these XML files into an XML table (2 columns: FileId and XmlData). This can be done as a 1st step of the package.
Then you will write a stored procedure and it will shred XML from this table into your final tables. This stored procedure will be called as a 2nd step in the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think it is easy to do that using SSIS**.

If you don't have other choices, you may use **a Script Component as Source** and parse the XML files using a C# or VB.NET script, then only generate output with desired columns.

You can refer to the following articles for more information about using Script component:

- [Creating a Source with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-source-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS Script Component Overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-script-component-overview/)

#### SchemaMapper class library

From a while, I was working on a project called SchemaMapper. It is a class library developed using C#. You can use it to import tabular data from XML, and other formats having different structures into a unified SQL server table.

- [SchemaMapper - C# schema mapping class library](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper)

You can refer to the project wiki for a step by step guide:

- [SchemaMapper Wiki](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/wiki)

---

Also, feel free to check the following answer, it may give you some insights:

- [How to Map Input and Output Columns dynamically in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781017/how-to-map-input-and-output-columns-dynamically-in-ssis/54797147)

Comment: This solution seems the most logical, thank you very much.